HTML content after loading page is blank in Pyppeteer
So I'm trying to use Pyppeteer (an unofficial Python port for Puppeteer), and I'm trying to scrape a site and try to select an element.
I been trying to wait for elements with the class "tab" for example
elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.tab')
But nothing returns and I get a timeout error.
In fact, I get a timeout error when I try to wait for any element with any class on the site that I loaded up. I tried to troubleshoot by writing the HTML and investigating that HTML, but not only don't I see any of the elements, but when I open it, my page is blank
This is my code so far
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import requests
import sys
import json

print("Test")
print("Starting script...")

def print_cookies_as_json(cookies):
    cookies_json = json.dumps(cookies, indent=4)
    print("Cookies in JSON format:")
    print(cookies_json)

async def main():
    try:
        print("Launching browser...")
        browser = await launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.newPage()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error launching browser or creating new page: {e}")
        return

    try:
        print("Reading cookies from file...")
        # Load cookies from JSON file
        try:
            with open('/path/to/usrCookies.json', 'r') as f:
                cookies = json.load(f)
            if not cookies:
                raise ValueError("No valid cookies found in the file.")
            await page.setCookie(*cookies)
        except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError) as e:
            print(f"Error reading cookies: {e}")
            return

        # Print cookies in JSON format
        print_cookies_as_json(cookies)

        print("Navigating to URL...")
        url = 'https://example.com'
        await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil': 'networkidle0'})
        response = requests.get(url, cookies={c['name']: c['value'] for c in cookies})
        json_response = response.json()
        print(json_response)

        print("Processing JSON data...")

        await page.screenshot({'path': 'screenshot_TEST.png', 'fullPage': True})
        print("Waiting for page to load...")
        await page.waitForSelector('body', {'timeout': 10000})  # wait for the body to load

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        # Get the HTML content of the page
        print("Getting HTML content...")
        html = await page.content()

        # Write the HTML content to a file
        with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
           file.write(html)

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        await page.screenshot({'path': 'screenshot_ERROR.png', 'fullPage': True})
        print("Screenshot saved as screenshot.png")
    finally:
        # Close the browser
        try:
            print("Closing browser...")
            await browser.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error closing browser: {e}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())

This is just a generic snippet of what my code looks like. Is there perhaps a flaw in how my code is executed?

Do you have the actual site? You're probably being blocked by cloudflare, if no elements are showing up. You're running headfully, so you should be able to look at the page and see what's there.

@ggorlen If I were to take a snapshot, the site is there, so I doubt I'm being blocked by cloudflare. Could it be something to do with the cookies?

It could be anything. I'd have to see the site to make a determination.

Try changing your write method. Change "html" to "str(html)" But I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse html. Try parsing your html with BS and then save.
r = await page.content()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

html = soup.find('table', class_='TABLEBORDER')

with open('files/output.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(str(html))

